# How to resolve dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart

My project **TT_info_mash** generates this error message:

> Because `flutter_form_builder >=4.0.0-alpha.3` depends on
> `flutter_localizations any` from `sdk` which depends on `intl0.17.0-nullsafety.2`,
> `flutter_form_builder >=4.0.0-alpha.3` requires `intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2`.
>
> So, because **TT_info_mash** depends on both `intl ^0.16.0` and
> `flutter_form_builder ^4.2.0`, version solving failed.
>
> pub get failed (1; So, because **TT_info_mash** depends on both
> `intl ^0.16.0` and `flutter_form_builder ^4.2.0`, version solving failed.)

**TT_info_mash** is a project with web support.

**How do I make it depend on `intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2` instead of `intl ^0.16.0`'.
And would that be a solution anyway?**

Comment: Why not switch to flutter form builder 4.2.0?

Comment: @barbecu I am on 4.2.0: dependencies: flutter_form_builder: ^4.2.0

Comment: @barbecu Actually, I wonder why pub get prints this: flutter_form_builder >=4.0.0-alpha.3

Comment: Why can't you make your `TT_info_mash` project depend on `intl: ^0.17.0-0` instead of `^0.16.0`?  You also can use [dependency overrides](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides) as a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best solution. but a temporary one. This must have happened after you applied an upgraded to flutter 2 or switched to master channel. So because the flutter now has null Safety and as a result most of the plugins have not updated yet. And this must have happened on a already existing project. Switch back to stable channel using "flutter channel stable" and downgrade to 1.22.6 by typing "flutter downgrade". FYI : you can try add this to pubspec.yaml. but it might not work some times. dependency_overrides: intl: 0.17.0-nullsafety.2